# Sending Token from A to B and in return receiving data from B to A in same transaction?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, tokens

Is it possible to send a cryptocurrency as a payment and in return getting data about a product that is shipped to you in one Ethereum Transaction like you can see in the attached picture? If yes, how? I would like to be able to recreate a supply chain only out of transactions that suppliers send to each other.

[image: Supply chain with Tier 2 and Tier 1 to Manufacturer. Payments are done in cryptocurrency and in return data is received about the product like a receipt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EIP-777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777) allows contracts to define a callback when they receive tokens.

For regular ERC20 tokens there's the approve+transferFrom mechanism. The owner will not make the transfer directly but only approves the recipient, which will be able to make the transfer by itself with transferFrom.

Comment: [An EIP-777 related exploit](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/exploiting-uniswap-from-reentrancy-to-actual-profit/1116).